# Facebook embedded player no longer working for unknown reason?

Tags: facebook, embedding

is anyone willing to help me with a fresh pair of eyes?

For the past few years I've run a music service that, until last week, would embed video on Facebook's stream and I have no idea why it stopped working.

The debugger shows no errors, and even has the status 'Video embedding on Facebook enabled,' but it still won't work. I've spent several days trying to resolve this issue to no avail.

Here is the URL. Will someone please have a look and let me know if they can see something I missed. I'd really appreciate it.

http://music.echoingwalls.com/cgi-bin/msplay.cgi?s=9-81

Comment: Did you solve it in any way? I seem to have the same issue... everything was alright until a few days ago.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. Looking over the past updates from Facebook though I'm going to purchase another secure certificate for my site so that everything is https, and not just where the music is stored and see if it solves the problem. I'll let you know if that works.

Comment: Actually yes I did solve it. Looking at the object browser the video source for some reason was reading http:// instead of https:// - I edited my .htaccess to force https for the domain name and presto! it's embedding again.

Answer (score 1):

Officially this is a bug with Facebook and it has been assigned and they are working on it.
Here is the link.

[Click here to see the official ticket information](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598397860207749?browse=external_tasks_search_results_528cfc8cea4c64557023076)